# Can I send firebase notification in a specific android version?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

My app is somehow crashing only on android 12. So I want to send notifications to only android 12 users. Is it possible by firebase FCM?

Answer (score 1):

Check if device is android 12 and if it is, then subscribe to a topic

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S || "S".equals(Build.VERSION.CODENAME)) {  //Check if it is android 12
   FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("android12")  //subscribe to topic ( Ex : android12 )
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                //subscribed
            }
        }
    });
}
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple

Then send fcm notifications to the topic (to which Android 12 devices have subscribed)

```
{
 "message":{
 "topic":"android12",
 "notification":{
   "body" : "",  //add body of notification
   "title" : "", //add title of notification
  }
 }
}
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message

Comment: Hi @Mai3, My live version has an issue with android 12. But, how can I add these codes to my live app? As I know it is not possible now. Let me know if it is possible.

Comment: I don't understand. Users cannot update your app?

Comment: Users can definitely update my app. But I need to send a notification to the affected users. If a user already updated the version why do I need to send a notification to them since it is fixed in the new version? I just want to send a notification to the affected users. Do you understand me?

Comment: Okay. Do you have fcm in your app? Did you store device tokens of your users? If yes, then send notification to all the device tokens. Users who are not affected can ignore that notification(mention it there).

Comment: Otherwise, if you have come code in your app where you display any message from your server, then send that message there. If you have send sms permission, then you can send sms (same for email). Please mention what solutions you tried and were not possible, so that people who don't know your app can think of solution, which you hadn't already thought of.

Comment: Yes, I have FCM in my app. Thank you for your solution. I also thought about sending a notification to all since I have nothing to do now except this.